React Native Expo Project - OTA Updates are only reaching half my users on first launch
I currently have my config set to:
"fallbackToCacheTimeout": 60000

This will wait for a whole minute before falling back. My update is only one single line of code. It is important for it to run on first launch as I'm trying to A/B test features for new users remotely without going through the app store every time.
I don't understand why this is failing 50% of the time, 60 seconds should be plenty of time. Is there some other factor here that can be causing unreliable OTA updates?
